# Indicator function and semirings in COQ

Tags: coq

I'm quite new with Coq, and I'm trying to define a "generic" indicator function, like this :

```
Function indicator (x : nat) : bool :=
  match x with
    | O => false
    | _ => true
  end.
```

This one works well.

My problem is that I want an indicator function that returns `false` for *the **identity element** of any **semiring*** (for which I have a personal definition), not just for the natural number zero, like this :

```
Function indicator `(S : Semiring) (x : K) : bool :=
  match x with
    | ident => false
    | _ => true
  end.
```

where `K` is defined in the semiring `S` as the set and `ident` is defined in the semiring `S`as the identity element.

This one doesn't work. I got the **error**:

```
This clause is redundant
```

with the last line of the `match` underlined. However, I don't think the error really comes from here. I read that it may come from the line

```
    | ident => false
```

because `ident` is a variable, but I don't have more clues.

Comment: I thought `identity` was a function? don't you mean `unit`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `unit` instead of `ident`, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: In classical logic, all semirings have the property `forall x, x = 0 \/ x <> 0`. In intuitionistic logic, only decidable semirings have that property. Equality on `nat` is decidable.

Comment: Another alternative besides using classical logic or adding an extra decidability hypothesis is to use [double‐negation translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nat` is an inductive type, created from two constructors:

```
Inductive nat: Set :=
    | O : nat
    | S : nat -> nat
 .
```

This means that any inhabitant of the `nat` type is always built by a combination of these 2 constructors.

You can "inspect" this construction by pattern matching, like you did in the first `indicator` definition.
In the second case, your type `K` is a type variable (you don't want to have a fix type like `nat`), so you didn't explain how to build elements of `K`. Then, when you pattern match, the `ident` your wrote is just a binder, any name would have had the same effect (and `_` too). It has no link to the `indent` of your semiring. Coq said that the clause is redundant because `ident` already captured any element of type `K`, so the `_` case is never called.

If you want to write such a function for any type `K`, you will have to provide a way to compare elements of `K` (something of the type `K -> K -> bool`) and use it in your indicator function. I'm not sure about the syntax but you'll have something link:

```
Record SemiRing : Type := mkSemiRing {    
    K: Type;
    ident : K;
    compare : K -> K -> bool;
    (* you might need the property that:
    forall x y, compare x y = true -> x = y
     *)
    op1 : K -> K -> K;
    op2 : K -> K -> K
    (* and all the laws of semiring... *)
}.

Definition indicator (ring: SemiRing) (x: K ring) : bool :=                                              
     if compare ring x (ident ring) then true else false.
```